# Calling Linked Lists functions in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

i have created 2 files called nodelist.h and nodelist.cpp, and basically the functions inside of them contains the basic linked list functions such as (eg. addNode,printNode...etc) Afterwards i have created another source file to utilize the functions created in that class like so:

```
#include "NodeList.h"

bool insertR(stringstream &lineStream)
{

    int node1,node2;
    lineStream>> node1 >> node2;
    nodelist *n1 = new nodelist; //EDIT: FIXED
    nodelist *n2 = new nodelist; // EDIT: FIXED
    n1->addNode(node1);
    n2->addNode(node2);
    n1->print();
    n2->print();
    return true;
}
```

note that this function isn't in main and it is another source file which is called by main. My nodelist.cpp works fine and although this program runs, when i input the node values my program crashes. Any help?

Here is my nodelist file:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "NodeList.h"

using namespace std;

nodelist::nodelist(){
                 head = NULL;
                 current = NULL;
                 temp = NULL;
}

void nodelist::addNode(int node_id_){
 nodePtr n = new Node;
 n->next = NULL;
 n->node_id = node_id_;
 if(head!=NULL)
 {
     current = head;
     while(current->next != NULL)
     {
         current = current ->next;                    
     }
     current->next = n;                    
 }
 else
 {
     head = n;    
 }
}

void nodelist::deleteNode(int del_node){
 nodePtr delPtr = NULL;
 temp = head;
 current = head;
 while(current!=NULL&&current->node_id!=del_node){
     temp = current;
     current = current->next;
     }
 if (current == NULL)
     {
         cout << del_node<<" does not exist"<<endl;   
         delete delPtr;         
     }
 else
     {
         delPtr = current;
         current  = current->next;
         temp->next= current;
         delete delPtr;
         cout << del_node<< " has been deleted"<<endl;      
     }
  }


 void nodelist::print(){
 current = head;
 while(current != NULL){
     cout << current->node_id<<endl;
     current = current ->next;       
 }
```

}

EDIT: so now it works when i create a new object of type nodelist, however when i pass in the values for node1 and node2 i get a continuous loop that doesn't correspond to either of the nodes. However, this works if i do this in main().

Answer (score 2):

Declaring pointers isn't enough, you need to use the new operator to instantiate the nodelists that they point to.

n1 and n2 don't point to anything which is why it crashes

```
nodelist *n1;
nodelist *n2;
n1->addNode(node1);
n2->addNode(node2);
```

Comment: but inside my nodelist file, my addNode function creates the new node.

Comment: No, you need to create the nodelist.  As soon as you try to call n1->addNode, it will crash because n1 points to nothing.

Answer (score 2):

```
nodelist *n1; // unintialized pointer
nodelist *n2; // another uninitialized pointer
n1->addNode(node1); // you try to use an uninitialized pointer
n2->addNode(node2); // same here
n1->print(); // and here
n2->print(); // and here!
```

Without seeing how you have your linked list class declared/implemented, it is difficult to give you a potential solution to your overall problem.  But the crash is being caused by your attempt to access random blocks of memory and treat them as a `nodelist` object (e.g. undefined behavior).

Comment: i have edited my question! and thanks but now i have a new error : (

Comment: Now you have a couple memory leaks, and you appear to be violating the principle of separation of concerns.  You should separate the list construct from the iterator construct.